# How to remove an option from a select element with Select2 applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So, I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="orders_lives_in_ccs" name="orders[lives_in_ccs]" class="lives_in_ccs">
<select id="orders_shipping_from" name="orders[shipping_from]" required="required" class="shipping_from toSelect2">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-- SELECCIONAR --</option>
    <option value="MRW">MRW - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>
    <option value="DOMESA">DOMESA - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>
    <option value="ZOOM">GRUPO ZOOM - COBRO EN DESTINO</option>
</select>
```

I need to remove the option `MRW` when checkbox `.lives_in_ccs` is checked so I made this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.toSelect2').select2();

    var detachedMember;
    $('.lives_in_ccs').click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            detachedMember = $('.shipping_from option[value="MRW"]').detach();
        } else {
            $('.shipping_from option[value=""]').after(detachedMember);
        }

        $(".secure_shipping").toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

This code works but I'm having a problem and didn't found the way to fixit. Having [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fgaqgpd7/) jsFiddle  do this tests:

- Leave the SELECT with the default value which is `--SELECCIONAR--` and mark the check in the left side, that will works and will remove the option `MRW` from the main SELECT, if you unmark the check the value will appear again on the SELECT
- Choose `MRW` (the first choice) on the SELECT and mark the check in the left side, that will remove the option `MRW` from the main SELECT, but will leave the option as SELECTED which is wrong since the server side isn't expecting it.

So, how do I remove the option even if it's selected on the SELECT element? Any help?

Comment: Maybe if MRW is selected when you click the checkbox, reset the value of the select to `--SELECCIONAR--`. I think there is a method in Select2 that allows you to change the selected value. I think it is `val`, but can't remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the updated fiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/fgaqgpd7/2/

This will reset the value of the select2 input:

```
$('.toSelect2').select2('val','');
```

You can apply it you click event handler. Basically if MRW is selected, then reset the select2 value.

```
$(function () {
    $('.toSelect2').select2();
    var detachedMember;
    $('.lives_in_ccs').click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            if ($('.toSelect2').select2('val') == 'MRW') {
                $('.toSelect2').select2('val','');
            }
            detachedMember = $('.shipping_from option[value="MRW"]').detach();
        } else {
            $('.shipping_from option[value=""]').after(detachedMember);
        }

        $(".secure_shipping").toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
if($(".lives_in_ccs").is(':checked')){ 
    $("#orders_shipping_from option[value='MRW']").remove();
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Select2 will still rerender it.

Answer (score 1):

For me in version Select2 4.0.13:

```
$('#my-form').on('change', '.checkbox-item', updateDropdown);
```

HTML object:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" id="checkbox_1" value="1" class="form-control checkbox-item" data-text="Label" />
```

Event function:

```
    function updateDropdown(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        if ($('#dropdown').select2('val') == $(this).val()) {
            $('#dropdown').select2('val', '');
        } else {
            var newOption = new Option($(this).attr('data-text'), $(this).val(), false, false);
            $('#dropdown').append(newOption).trigger('change');
        }
    } else {
        $('#dropdown option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').detach();
    }
}
```